# Django "Page not found" error page shows only one of two expected urls

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, urlconf

I'm working with Django, admittedly for the first time doing anything real.

The URL config looks like the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('my_site.core_prototype.views',

    (r'^newpost/$', 'newPost'),

    (r'^$', 'NewPostAndDisplayList'), # capture nothing...


    #more here... - perhaps the perma-links?
)
```

This is in an app's url.py which is loaded from the project's url.py via:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # only app for now.
    (r'^$', include('my_site.core_prototype.urls')),
)
```

The problem is, when I receive a 404 attempting to utilize `newpost`, the error page only shows the `^$` -- it seems to ignore the `newpost` pattern...

I'm sure the solution is probably stupid-simple but right now I'm missing it. Can someone help get me on the right track...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern for the include will only match an empty URL string, change it to a prefix which should be mapped to the included urls, or remove the $ from that pattern.

Comment: Got it. I removed the `$` from the project's url.py and it worked as it should. Thank you.